# Segmentation fault when inserting data

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently trying to insert data in a method which will then be added in a vector. For some reason, I'm always getting the segmentation fault when I reach the point of inputting the 2nd set of x y.

This is the part where i believe that's causing the fault:

```
    if (shape == "square") {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter x-coordinate of pt." << i+1 << " : ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Please enter y-coordinate of pt." << i+1 << " : ";
        cin >> y;

        sq->setName(shape);
        sq->setContainsWarpSpace(type);
        sq->setVertices(i,x,y);

        shapes.push_back(sq);
    }
}
```

The `setName` and `setContainsWarpSpace` are normal set methods.

**EDIT**
Okay i just found the line that's causing the segmentation fault.
Its my `setName` method

```
void ShapeTwoD::setName(string name) {
this->name = name;
}
```

**EDIT2**
As requested this is the definition of both name and shape. And yes, sq is a pointer of `Square` class.

Inside driver class:

```
string shape;
```

Inside ShapeTwoD class:

```
class ShapeTwoD {
private:
string name;
bool containsWarpSpace;
double area;
};
```

Any idea why is this causing the fault?

Comment: yup - there is something wrong with the code that you're not showing us. WHat does the debugger say? Where did sq come from for a start

Comment: @pm100 sq is a Square object. And Square is a subclass of ShapeTwoD

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `name` in your class and the definition of `shape`. Also, did `sq` is a pointer ? I mean `Square *sq = new Square();`. If it's `Square sq;`, then you should call `setName` like this : `sq.setName(shape);`.

Comment: @GabrielL. Done. Please take a look at Edit2. Thanks

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `sq`?

Comment: @Chad Do you mean this `sq->setName(shape)`?

Comment: Can you show us the line when you define your pointer `sq` ?

Comment: @GabrielL. It is under my Driver class in the private section. `Square* sq;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that the sq pointer is not initialised because that seems to be the problem.
If I write and execute the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    void SetName(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
        cout<<this->name<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* obj = new A();
    obj->SetName("test");
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and executes perfectly. If, however, I change the line:

```
A* obj = new A();
```

with:

```
A* obj = NULL;
```

then I get a SEGFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string into the setName(string name) function, which defaults to pass by value. You are assigning it as a reference though, because you are referring to the member data name as this->name using the pointer operator. I think that might be why you are getting a segfault. Make sure that string name in ShapeTwoD is not a pointer and don't refer to it as one. Also check that string shape that you are passing into the function is also not declared as a pointer.

Comment: I have checked that the name and shape isn't a pointer. Is it something that I have to change in my `setName` method?

Comment: Looking at Vag's answer. I just noticed that you don't seem to be initializing a new instance of sq in your loop which could be causing the segfault due to a null reference error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that shapes is a

```
vector<ShapeTwoD*>;
```

If that's the case, your code will not do what you want even if it doesn't seg fault.

You are pushing the same pointer of `ShapeTwoD*` to the vector shapes and as a result, all entries in that vector will point to the same memory location, they will all be equal to the last sq you pushed to the vector.

Use a 
`vector<ShapeTwoD>` instead or make sure you allocate a `new ShapeTwoD()` every time you want to push a new entry to shapes. So

```
vector<ShapeTwoD> shapes;
sd->setName(name);
... 
shapes.push_back(*sd);
```

or

```
vector<ShapeTwoD*> shapes;
ShapeTwoD* newSd = new ShapeTwoD();
newSd->setName(name);
... 
shapes.push_back(newSd);
```

Don't forget to free the memory in shapes when your done with it if you choose to use a vector

```
for(vector<ShapeTwoD*>::iterator it = shapes.begin(); it != shapes.end(); it++){
   delete *it;
}
```